# How to import python extension module that has the same name as a pure python package with subpackages and modules?

Tags: python, package, pybind11

I have a project with pybind11 extension modules, structured in a hierarchical way.

While importing, I face the following problem:

### 1. Test 1

#### 1.1. Package structure

```
org
├── __init__.py
├── sdk
│   ├── core.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
│   └── __init__.py
└── sdk.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

#### 1.2. Import type from module org.sdk:

```
python -c "from org.sdk import CommonType"
```

1.2.1. Fails with the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'CommonType' from 'org.sdk' (python3.7/site-packages/org_sdk-0.0.0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/org/sdk/__init__.py)
```

#### 1.3. Import type from module org.sdk.core:

```
python -c "from org.sdk.core import A"
```

1.3.1. Success

### 2. Test 2

Removed `org/sdk/__init__.py`

#### 2.1. Package structure

```
org
├── __init__.py
├── sdk
│   └── core.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
└── sdk.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

#### 2.2. Import type from module org.sdk:

```
python -c "from org.sdk import CommonType"
```

2.2.1. Success

#### 2.3. Import type from module org.sdk.core:

```
python -c "from org.sdk.core import A"
```

2.3.1. Fails with the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org.sdk.core'; 'org.sdk' is not a package
```

I'd like to know how can I have a solution where both imports would work?

It seems that the default python loader, prefers the `org/sdk/__init__.py` to load the `org.sdk` package, is it possible to add some code in the org/sdk/**init**.py that would also load the pybind11 extension module `org/sdk.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` ?

Answer (score 0):

A common practice to mix python and C++ in same package is to name pure-C++ module with leading underscore and import from it in python module.

The layout will look like that:

```
org
├── __init__.py
└── sdk
    ├── __init__.py # import ._core as core
    └── _core.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```